# How to test database migration in Android?

Tags: android, database

I have an Android app with a database with version 1.

Now I like to change the structure of the database and write all the migration code etc.

The problem I have is how to test this.

I need to repeatedly have the old version of the app with its old DB so I can test the update process to the new app with the new DB several times.

I thought to simplify things I make a copy of my project and just rename it new - leaving the manifest and everything unchanged!!!!

The idea is to run/install the old version of the app with the old DB structure using Eclipse so I can create the start situation of my update.

Now to simulate the user update to the new app version I install it just over the old version using Eclipse again) - but even without having changed the db I get an error that the DB already exists ???

I am confused (I have only changed the project name, not the manifest) I would have expected that I can just install the new version over the old version and hereby test the user update of the app.

But that does not work.

How would I best do this? (without having the old and the new database code in the very same project. since if I have the same project I have two different data base structures in there and need to build in a switch how it should start up, ie as old or new. I find it cleaner to just write the new version of the app with the new database structure in there)

Comment: Are you using some orm like ORMlite or greenDAO?

Comment: no, its just a simple database - nothing complex really

Comment: Have you extended the SQLiteOpenHelper class?

Comment: yes, all that is no issue. The question is how to simulate the update from the old to the new app more than once, since if I run my new app version it destroys the old one and I can't repeat this process until I re-create the exact same old situation again...

Comment: The only way I foudn was to implement BOTH DB versions in one app and be able to switch back and forth so the old DB can be created anytime to test the migration to the new version more than once...

Comment: @user387184 did you find a better solution?

Comment: no - that's exactly what I had to do - but it did not work reliably and I still had major hickups when I release the new version ;-) So it is a REAL CRITICAL issue IMHO, but there seems to be no good solution for that!

Answer (score 2):

**Room** is one of the Android Architecture Components for database stuff.

**Room** provides a testing Maven artifact to assist with this testing process.

First you need to export db scheme by set the `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor property in your `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                             "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
}


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MigrationTest {
    private static final String TEST_DB = "migration-test";

    @Rule
    public MigrationTestHelper helper;

    public MigrationTest() {
        helper = new MigrationTestHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
                MigrationDb.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory());
    }

    @Test
    public void migrate1To2() throws IOException {
        SupportSQLiteDatabase db = helper.createDatabase(TEST_DB, 1);

        // db has schema version 1. insert some data using SQL queries.
        // You cannot use DAO classes because they expect the latest schema.
        db.execSQL(...);

        // Prepare for the next version.
        db.close();

        // Re-open the database with version 2 and provide
        // MIGRATION_1_2 as the migration process.
        db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(TEST_DB, 2, true, MIGRATION_1_2);

        // MigrationTestHelper automatically verifies the schema changes,
        // but you need to validate that the data was migrated properly.
    }
}
```

You can read an official document [for more info](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#db-migration)

Comment: MIGRATION_1_2 value is comming null. Even I have set it as @VisibleForTesting

Answer (score 1):

You can create the main file 'create.sql' and the migrations files called '1.sql, 2.sql,.., n.sql'. 
Store all these files in assets for example.

If the user has no database, apply create.sql
If the user needs a database upgrade from A to Z, then apply a+1.sql, a+2.sql, …, z.sql.

You need implement applyUpgrades method that you'll use on upgrade version of DB and for migration tests. It's look like:

```
fun Context.applyUpgrades(db: SQLiteDatabase, from: Int, to: Int): Unit =
    (from+1..to).forEach { index ->
      val migrationSql = getMigrationFromAssets(index)
      db.execSQL(migrationSql)
    }
```

Your migration tests will look like:

```
@Test
fun upgrade10to11() { // when you upgrade from 10 to 11

    val db = SQLiteDatabase.create(null)

    // apply all previous migrations
    applyUpgrades(db, from = INITIAL, to = 10)  

    val valuesBefore = ..

    // our new migration
    applyUpgrades(db, from = 10, to = 11)

    val valuesAfter = ..

    // assert that valuesBefore and valuesAfter are correct
}
```

Also you can check that you did not forget write test for new migration:

```
@Test
public void hasAllNecessaryTests() {
  assertEquals(DB_VERSION, 11);
}
```

[Trello bless](http://tech.trello.com/android-schemas/)

Answer (score 0):

As you only need the data and structures to test migration, you could make backups of the old databases and use them in your tests.

So for each test:

- install app, put data in, make backup (once)
- restore backup, run test (often)

That way you only have to make the backup once and can restore them on every test.
If your tests are automated, you could even restore the backups automatically as well.

For SQLite, making backups is as easy as copying the database file, but pretty much every database has a way to make and restore backups.

Your updated app seems to try to create the database (not the data inside) again, but with the database of the old app still being around that won't work.
This may be caused by the app not noticing it was installed before.